# „Zum einen“ ohne „zum anderen“

Tags: phrase, idiom, style

Betrachten wir folgende Beispiele:

1. „Dieser Aufsatz will zum einen in die Zubereitung von Suppen einführen, konzentriert sich aber zwangsläufig vor dem Hintergrund der Fülle der Materialien auf die grundlegende Zubereitung von Brühen, hat aber darüber hinaus den Anspruch, einen Ansatz besonders stark zu betonen, der im Mittelpunkt das Thema der Würfelbrühen als zentrales Instrument nutzt. Ein weiterer Aspekt betrifft nicht nur die Zubereitung von Suppen und Brühen, sondern auch deren Servierung.“
2. „Suppen bringen – verglichen mit Fragen zu Brühen – zusätzliche Komplexität mit sich. Das betrifft zum einen den grundsätzlichen Umgang mit Suppen und damit auch mit wässrigen Lösungen allgemein. Das hat auch damit zu tun, dass diese Art von Kochkunst oft mit anderen Vorgängen in der Küche interagiert, wie man das etwa am Beispiel des Umgangs mit Wasserhahn und Kochplatten sieht.“

In diesen Beispiel sieht man „zum einen“ ohne „zum anderen“. Ist das grammatikalisch? Wenn ja: Ist das wirklich guter Stil im Rahmen eines Fachbuchs?

Comment: There are two kinds of people: those who can extrapolate from incomplete data

Comment: On a serious note though, could you please add the sources of those quotes?

Comment: @Tsundoku Sorry; being on an NDA, I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammatikalisch ist es nicht zu beanstanden, aber es verwirrt den Leser: Man erwartet tatsächlich danach ein "zum anderen". Die Funktion von "zum einen - zum anderen" ist eine Aufzählung, man könnte auch "erstens - zweitens" oder ggf. "a) - b)" verwenden.

Statt des erwarteten "zum anderen" findet man bei Beispiel 1. immerhin die Redewendung "hat aber darüber hinaus den Anspruch" als zweite Aufzählungskomponente.

1. Dieser Aufsatz will **zum einen** in die Zubereitung von Suppen einführen, konzentriert sich aber zwangsläufig vor dem Hintergrund der Fülle der Materialien auf die grundlegende Zubereitung von Brühen, **hat aber darüber hinaus den Anspruch**, einen Ansatz besonders stark zu betonen, der im Mittelpunkt das Thema der Würfelbrühen als zentrales Instrument nutzt. Ein weiterer Aspekt betrifft nicht nur die Zubereitung von Suppen und Brühen, sondern auch deren Servierung.

M.E. ist das stilistisch unschön, aber immerhin verständlich. Bei Beispiel 2. fehlt die zweite Aufzählungskomponente - und das ist definitiv schlechtes Deutsch. Hier ein Vorschlag für eine Ergänzung (wobei ich nicht beurteilen kann, ob das so im Sinne des Verfassers ist; er könnte den Satz "Das hat ... " vielleicht als Erläuterung des vorigen Satzes gemeint haben).

2. Suppen bringen – verglichen mit Fragen zu Brühen – zusätzliche Komplexität mit sich. Das betrifft **zum einen** den grundsätzlichen Umgang mit Suppen und damit auch mit wässrigen Lösungen allgemein. Das hat **zum anderen** auch damit zu tun, dass diese Art von Kochkunst oft mit anderen Vorgängen in der Küche interagiert, wie man das etwa am Beispiel des Umgangs mit Wasserhahn und Kochplatten sieht.

Comment: Bei 2. findet sich die zweite Aufzählungskomponente nach **damit auch**: Das betrifft **zum einen** den grundsätzlichen Umgang mit Suppen und **damit auch** mit wässrigen Lösungen allgemein.